# Integration In App Purchase Popup

Tags: ios, xcode, popup, in-app-purchase

I'm iOS developer for a few months and I am currently developing an application with a store (Subscription renewable).

The integration of the IAP seems to work as I can buy and restore my products with the test account.

However I have a popup just constantly disrupt the user experience which I do not control its appearance.
This popup indicates that a connection is required and that I must log in to continue. (It appears even when the app is in background see screenshot attached)

In theory this popup will have to appear at the time I made ​​my purchase and not before.

Does somebody of you knows what causes this popup and why it appears all the time?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please attach the screenshot

Comment: Are you trying to access the Store during that period for any purpose? E.g. if you are trying to restore transactions it will surely ask for the login information.